# I cannot move multiple files by drag and drop method

Tags: 20.04, files, filesystem, copy, drag-and-drop

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

My problem is when I want to move some files to another place, I'm selecting files then trying to move but the selections disappearing and this way I can move only one file. Or if I try to move with hold on 'ctrl' this time I can move every files except one.

I want to use drag and drop like in Windows OS

How can I solve this problem?

This is problem video, you may want to see:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NZ5r-q3pp7gE5-HOIfjCSg_977-xckf4/view?usp=sharing

This is the first time I am asking a question in a forum. Sorry if I have any mistakes.

Comment: Restore Drag & Drop in Ubuntu 20.04<br>
hope this link helps:
https://sudofry.com/2020/06/02/restore-drag-drop-in-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: @eqzhou's solution worked for me

Answer (score -1):

1. click and drag the pointer over all of the files which you would like to select
2. hold down shift while you drag and drop them into the desired folder

Comment: This may not be a solution to his problem... I believe he rather needs the functionality which may be missing from his operating system.

Comment: As stated by the OP, this does not work. Doing this moves all the file except the one used to drag.